# Comma delimited list of numbers in java

Tags: java

I am given interface  based on comma delimited Collections.. and I'm required to implements..

And I am failing to come up will the solution for this

```
 import java.util.Collection;
 /**
  * Implement this Interface to produce a comma delimited list of numbers,
  * grouping the numbers into a range when they are sequential.
  *
  *
  * Sample Input: "1,2,6,7,8,9,12,13,14,15,21,22,23,24,25,31
  * Result: "[[1],[2], [6,7,8], [13,14,15], [21-25], [32]]"
  *
  */
  public interface CommaDelimatedList {
      public Collection<Integer> coll(String input);
      public String summarizeColl(Collection<Integer> input);

  }
```

Can someone help me on how to implements this interface..

Comment: What have you tried? Please post some code of your attempt.

Comment: this what i have tried up to so far. coll(String []input){       Arrays.sort(input);   List<List<Integer>> ListMain = new ArrayList<>();        List<Integer> temp = new ArrayList(); temp.addAll(temp);
         for (int i = 0; i < input.length - 1; i++) {
             if (input[i + 1] != input[i] ) {
                 temp.add(input[i + 1]);
             } else {
                 ListMain.add(temp);
                 temp = new ArrayList<>();
                 temp.add(input[i+1]);
             }
         }

         return ListMain.add(temp);}

Comment: Welcome @SmurtD! We're here to help, but we're not going to do the work for you. I suggest you read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and update the question itself (perhaps with the code from your comment) and describe how what you're trying doesn't do what you expect.